# PHP: Is it bad practice to jump into PHP just to comment?

Tags: php, html, comments

I know this seems rather trivial, but I haven't heard anyone talk about it, and I'm curious.

Suppose I want to make a comment in my markup, but I don't want the comment to be visible in the source code. **Is it bad practice to jump into PHP tags just to make a comment then jump back out into the markup?**

Here's what I mean:

```
<div>
    <?php // this is my comment ?>
    <div>Hello world</div>
</div>
```

I know readability is important, but my question is speaking directly to the principle of unnecessarily jumping in and out of PHP tags.

Is it more work to jump in and out like that? Is there a reason you would or wouldn't do this? Does it even matter? etc.

---

Like I said, I know it's pretty trivial, but I appreciate your time and help. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want to show your comments in source code i mean browser view source option then you have no option without writing comments in php. But it is good idea to write comments.I would recommend you instead of writing comment such a way you did. try to write comments using http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html . it will help you in long run

Comment: its just a comment, dont worry too much. If it helps to clarify the statement, by all means put a comment around it

Comment: I think complex comments aren't really needed in proper markups because they are selfexplaining.

Comment: I can't really think of a situation where I would care that much about hiding a comment in the HTML. What kind of stuff are you actually trying to hide? If it's a comment about the PHP code then you shouldn't be mixing it in with your HTML to begin with which would likely indicate an even bigger problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no other way to hide comments from the HTML source code.
2. Yes, it's more work for the PHP compiler but the delay will be minimal.
3. I think the readability is certainly more important than few additional nanoseconds of executing time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should keep comments about your PHP code within your PHP code, and comments about your HTML within HTML. Unless you care about the extra x bytes worth of bandwith, it's not really going to matter much.

You can even think of your HTML comments as a way to search your PHP (or template) code, that way you can easily see in what file some structure is defined.